# How to make a webpack library that can be consumed in React Application?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

How can I create a webpack library ES6, that can be consumed in ReactJS. Like

```
-----lib.js-----
export function sum(a , b) {
    return a + b;
};

export function multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b;
};
```

I want to consume using import statements like:-

```
import lib from './lib';
console.log(lib.sum(3,5));
```

I am using following as webpack.config.babel.js

```
export default () => (
    {
        entry: './src/lib.js',
        output: {
            path: './dist',
            filename: 'lib.js',
            libraryTarget: 'umd',
            library: 'lib'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}
            ]
        },
    }
);
```

.babelrc file contains following configuration

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

package.json contents

```
{
  "name": "lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/lib.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:lib": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-webpack": "^6.4.3",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Paste `package.json` of your library,  if you have your library code in a separate package than the react component which is using it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is proper other than the way you are importing, use this to import all the function defined in this file:

```
import * as lib from './lib';
```

Now you can use any function by `lib.sum(1,2);`

**Reason**: you are exporting many functions so you need to import each function separately or use * to import all.

**Alternate way:**

use `module.exports` to export many methods, `lib.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    sum: function(a,b){
       return a + b; 
    },

    multiply: function(a,b){
       return a * b; 
    }
}
```

import this file by:

```
import Lib from "lib";
```

Now use it by `lib.sum(1,2);`

Reference: https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/build-better-apps-with-es6-modules

Comment: Its not working for me. I added my webpack config file in question.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things pop out:

- If you export everything, you should also import everything:

  ```js
  import * as lib from './lib';
  ```

  (as stated in a deleted answer by @MayankShukla)
- `output.path` [must be absolute](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#output-path):

  ```js
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      // ...
  ```

Comment: benefit of having 10k reputation you can see the deleted answer :)

Comment: right @MayankShukla, changing *"**the** deleted answer"* to *"**a** deleted answer"* :)